# what should be the minimum age of sharks that fall in different grades

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, exploratory-data-analysis

I have data on sharks. that data contains basic spec. about sharks like length, breadth, age, etc.
Sharks have assigned ratings A,B,C,D,E based upon a combination of features.
I want to estimate what is the minimum age for sharks to fall in grade E.
Please tell me how to approach this problem.

Comment: You collected a sample of sharks with rating E (and others) and now wish to estimate what is the theoretical minimum age of this group?

Comment: Yes, Exactly   Can you suggest any approach?

Comment: If I were doing this, I would try a quantile regression model, estimating some low enough quantile such as 1 % maybe, as an approximation to the "minimum" age of sharks in each group (including E).

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't include much detail, so I'm going to assume based on your tags that you're using the shark specs to predict a rating based on something like regression.

The probability of a shark being in grade E will be based on age, but also the other specs like length, breadth etc.  One approach would be to calculate the average of those other traits, and then use your model to work out the probability of the shark being in grade E at a range of ages, while holding the other variables constant at their average. Using this method you could plot probability of being grade E against age, and see if there's a minimum age above which the probability rises above zero.

Comment: No, I am trying to predict anything but the dataset contains the spec. about sharks and the corresponding grade. I don't know much about how they assigned the grades to sharks because that is out of domain knowledge.

Comment: I have a sample of sharks with rating E. and want to estimate the threshold age or minimum age of shark that falls in grade E.

Comment: Well then you could use your shark data to build a logistic regression model... The response would 1 if a shark is grade E, 0 if the shark is another grade; the predictors would be age, length, breadth etc.  Then follow the advice in my answer.

Comment: I am not trying to predict anything. It was a mistake in the above comment

Comment: I understand that - I'm suggesting you build a predictive model as it will give you info about the probability of shark being in grade E at different ages.